# How to trigger python.exe has stopped working

Tags: python

**Background:**
In order to troubleshoot some crashing python programs, I want to create a stacktrace. Now it just says `python.exe has stopped working`.

In order to do so, I would like to trigger a fault like this, so I can check if the stacktraces work.

**Question:**
How can I make a python program crash with the `python.exe has stopped working` on my local Windows machine? Preferably from a console app.

I tried creating a python program which calls a C++ dll, and calls a function which contains an access violation. When I do this, it still just shows me a stacktrace.

I also tried to keep opening files untill I ran out of memory. It still shows me a `MemoryError`, with the line number where the operation failed.

Thank you!

Comment: It's impossible to know from this information exactly what the crash condition was, and therefore how to reliably reproduce it... does Event Viewer tell you more?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I know, therefore I'm not asking to reproduce the crash condition. I am trying to create a condition which makes the program in the same way. This way I can implement and test a way of logging, which I can use to find where the real program actually crashes.

Comment: That's literally... reproducing it... at the very least you need to know _how_ to reproduce it if you want to know what it was in order to trigger the same thing in some other way.

Comment: Okay, I think I worded it wrong: it does not matter if the same thing (access violation, memory error, etc) caused the crash. I want to crash my python process at a deep enough level to get the same dialog. This way I can see what options I have available for logging and tracing...

Comment: Question is closed now, but http://www.acq4.org/documentation/devGuide/debugging.html gives an example on how to trigger this.